# WPF C# - column content alignment and style depending on content

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid, styles

I have a datagrid with 3 columns. The very last column only shows wether the dataset of the row is enabled or disabled by showing a "✓" or a "✗".
I want to set a style for that last column so the content alignment is center and depending of the content the "text" should be green (for the "✓") or red (for the "✗"). So how can I achieve that?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="employeesDataGrid" Margin="5,55,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="172" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" MinRowHeight="10" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Single" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameHeader" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.nameHeader}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="surnameHeader" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.surnameHeader}" Width="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="isenabledHeader" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.isenabledHeader}" MinWidth="50">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How can I style the cells different depending on the "✓" and "✗"?
Here is how I fill the datagrid with C#.

```
nameHeader.Binding = new Binding("Name");
surnameHeader.Binding = new Binding("Surname");
isenabledHeader.Binding = new Binding("IsEnabled");

employeesDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
Employee employee = new Employee();
// returns a List<Employee>
employeesList = employee.GetAll();
employeesDataGrid.ItemsSource = employeesList;
```

**Edit**
I figured out how to align the text of the cells by myself. Code is updated. So now I want to color it green or red. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you set the check or X? Are they images? I see your third column is bound to Employee.IsEnabled, but when do the "✓" and "✗" come in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "✓" and "✗" is string values You can add `DataTriggers` into the `CellStyle` of your `DataGridTextColumn` like this. In my test example I've used string value `first` for green color (you should change it to "✓").

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
                           Path=Content.Text}" Value="first">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: haha, you read foreground, I read background! I think you're probably right though :). It would look prettier to have a green check, not a green cell!

Comment: @bars222 Works perfect. Thank you very much! To clear some questions the "✓" and "✗" are strings provided by the class as an alternative method for the boolean values. Oh and yes I wanted to change the `Foreground` color :) Still the answer works for background colors as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it doesn't really matter how you bring in the "✓" and "✗" really. If I understand correctly that you would like to set the cell background color to green or red, here's a xaml solution:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="isenabledHeader" Header="Is Enabled" MinWidth="50">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Another (safe, I hope) assumption I made is that IsEnabled is a property on your Employee class. All we're doing here is creating a couple of DataTriggers that bind to IsEnabled, and set the background of the cell to the appropriate color. Note that I had to change the horizontalalignment of the DataGridCell to be "Stretch" in order to fill in the whole cell. The additional DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle should account for the centering that you desire.

Note: You can add the DataTriggers in code behind if you wish, but I personally can never remember the syntax so I didn't put it in my answer :).